# Table responsive layout CSS / HTML

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-table

I have not found the exact example for this so please point me to a link if you have. I had also made a mistake in my prev question so I awarded a correct answer but I still need help!

I want to make a table in HTML be responsive as follows - is it possible with CSS?

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <td>HEADER Data 1</td>
         <td>HEADER Data 2</td>
         <td>HEADER Data 3</td>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
         <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
         <td>Row 1 Data 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
         <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
         <td>Row 2 Data 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Row 3 Data 1</td>
         <td>Row 3 Data 2</td>
         <td>Row 3 Data 3</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

On small screens I want the table responsive so that is places the data as follows:

**FROM THIS:**

```
HEADER Data 1    HEADER Data 2   HEADER Data 3
Row 1 Data 1     Row 1 Data 2    Row 1 Data 3
Row 2 Data 1     Row 2 Data 2    Row 2 Data 3
Row 3 Data 1     Row 3 Data 2    Row 3 Data 3
```

**TO THIS:**

```
HEADER Data 1
Row 1 Data 1
Row 2 Data 1
Row 3 Data 1

HEADER Data 2
Row 1 Data 2
Row 2 Data 2
Row 3 Data 2

HEADER Data 3
Row 1 Data 3
Row 2 Data 3
Row 3 Data 3
```

Comment: I guess it is either very difficult or nearly impossible(??) with <table>, you should use <div>s to make your design flexible and responsive.

Comment: Hi @Thangadurai thanks for the response. This is what I think too, that is why I thought to ask the collective SO brain. I cannot change the layout as it is built by a templated system

Comment: Can you please provide an example with data where it should be user friendly to split a table into blocks of columns? In a default data table the rows belongs together. Why should it be necessary to show first all surnames in a block, then all given names in a second block, then all birthdays in a third block?

Comment: Hi @Axel Richter, it is not a question of whether the data makes sense when re-formatted, but rather it is a question about the layout change I am trying to achieve. The "data" in the CMS I am working with is actually a bunch of input fields with labels. The question is can the "re-formatting" be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To split a table into blocks of its columns is not possible with CSS. Therefore Javascript is needed. Like so:

```
<body>
<h1>Test</h1>

<table id="responsiveTable">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <td>HEADER Data 1</td>
         <td>HEADER Data 2</td>
         <td>HEADER Data 3</td>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
         <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
         <td>Row 1 Data 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
         <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
         <td>Row 2 Data 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Row 3 Data 1</td>
         <td>Row 3 Data 2</td>
         <td>Row 3 Data 3</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<hr>

<script>
var table = document.getElementById("responsiveTable");

var changeTable = function(e) {
 if (document.body.clientWidth < 400) {
  if (document.getElementById("responsiveTable")) {
   var tr = null;
   var td = null;
   var cols = [];

   for ( i=0; i<table.getElementsByTagName("tr").length; i++ ) {
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i];
    for ( j=0; j<tr.getElementsByTagName("td").length; j++) {
     td = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")[j];
     if(cols[j]==null) cols[j]=[];
     cols[j][i] = td;
    }
   }

   var divWrapper = document.createElement("div");
   divWrapper.id = "divWrapper";
   var divCol = null;
   var divData = null;

   for ( j=0; j<cols.length; j++ ) {
    divCol = document.createElement("div");
    for ( i=0; i<cols[j].length; i++ ) {
     divData = document.createElement("div");
     divData.innerHTML = cols[j][i].innerHTML;
     divCol.appendChild(divData);
    }
    divWrapper.appendChild(divCol);
   }
   document.body.replaceChild(divWrapper, table);
  }
 } else if (document.getElementById("divWrapper")) {
   document.body.replaceChild(table, document.getElementById("divWrapper"));
 }
}

window.addEventListener("load", changeTable, true);
window.addEventListener("resize", changeTable, true);

</script>

</body>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ch3sqx8j/

Greetings

Axel

Comment: Hey @Axel Richter, not the answer I was hoping for (intrigued with doing it with CSS) but EXCELLENT help, so thank you!

Comment: downvoting as CSS definitely should be the controller of this, not js

Comment: @treyBake: Then please add an answer that shows how to solve that requirement using CSS only. Good luck.

Comment: @AxelRichter o.O making a responsive table with css only? That's like.. the standard today ..

Comment: @treyBake: You have seen that the requirement here was
splitting a table into blocks of it's columns? As said, please post an answer. I am curious.

Comment: @AxelRichter to me that's a HTML structure issue that should be marked up correctly first

Comment: @treyBake: Yes, but that was explicitly **not** the question here. As I thought already. Big noise, nothing behind.

Comment: @AxelRichter but it's still the solution - I'd much rather offer best practice than a hack